# Why are my images are not being cached in AlamofireImage?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, tvos, alamofireimage

I am clueless at the moment, I dont know why I am getting nil each time when I am trying to retrieve. I am passing the correct image data and identifier. Here's a little code

```
 let photoCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
        memoryCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60 * 1024 * 1024
    )

 func cacheImage(image: Image, urlString: String) {

        print("Image size: \(image.size) and string as identifier: \(urlString)")



        self.photoCache.addImage(image, withIdentifier: urlString)
    }

    func cachedImage(urlString: String) -> Image? {

        print("What is url? : \(urlString)")

        print("What we are actually returning? : \(self.photoCache.imageWithIdentifier(urlString))")

        return self.photoCache.imageWithIdentifier(urlString)
    }
```

Print for the cacheImage function: Image size: (2826.0, 3722.0) and string as identifier: http:www.somelink.com/DT199.jpg

Print for the cachedImage when I am trying retrieving it: what is the URL? : http:www.somelink.com/DT199.jpg What we are actually returning is : nil

I don't know why it is happening I tried it several times before and it worked perfectly. I also read about these functions, they don't return any boolean response through which we can get to know whether the image is in cache or not.

Later on, i tried using the download manager as well nothing happen still clueless. If any one can help me? here's the code

```
 let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(
            configuration: ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration(),
            downloadPrioritization: .FIFO,
            maximumActiveDownloads: 15,
            imageCache: AutoPurgingImageCache()
        )


       let downloader = imageDownloader


        Alamofire.request(.GET, request, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

        self.imagesArray = NSMutableArray()
        self.imagesArray = JSON["results"] as! NSMutableArray

            for results in self.imagesArray{

            let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:results["url"] as! String)!)

            downloader.downloadImage(URLRequest: URLRequest, filter: nil, completion: { response in

                if response.response?.statusCode == 200{

                    print("In the house fetching url: \(results["url"] as! String)")

                    let image = response.result.value
                    print("Size of image: \(image?.size)")
                    let returnValue = downloader.imageCache?.addImage(image!, withIdentifier: results["url"] as! String)
                    print("return status: \(returnValue)")

                    if results .isEqual(self.imagesArray.lastObject){
                        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true

                        let fic = self.imagesArray.firstObject
                        print("getting image for this url : \(fic!["url"] as! String)")

                        var imageC = UIImage()
                        imageC = (downloader.imageCache?.imageWithIdentifier(fic!["url"] as! String))!
                        self.ssImage.image = imageC
                        print("Image : \(imageC.size))")

                    }


                }


            })


        }




        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to initialize your imageDownloader with the photoCache you used before to cache the images manually. The AutoPurgingImageCache isn't a shared instance. Only the UIImageView+AlamofireImage.swift extension has a af_sharedImageDownloader which keeps one AutoPurgingImageCache.

In dependence on your code example it should look like this:

```
let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(
            configuration: ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration(),
            downloadPrioritization: .FIFO,
            maximumActiveDownloads: 15,
            imageCache: self.photoCache
        )
```